# Can malformed XML cause a server timeout?

Tags: xml, soap, timeout

Is it possible for the contents of the XML in a SOAP request to be the cause of a server timeout?

I am working with a SOAP web service, running an application at regular intervals, and each time the application is run multiple requests are sent to the same endpoint, with the same headers, etc. The only difference is that the contents of the XML are changed, because the service can only handle 100 items per request.

Every time the application is run, most (often all) of the requests are received and processed successfully. Sometimes some of the requests time out, but never all the requests in a single interval of the application. When I contact support for the web service to troubleshoot the intermittent timeouts, the response is that I need to send the XML, so they can replicate the timeout on their end.

Is it possible that this tech support agent knows something I don't, and that the contents of an XML string can cause a time out?

In case it matters, I wrote the tool in VB.Net, 4.6.1, and the `exception.toString`=`System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at SolutionName.ModuleName.SubName(String MyXMLString)`. I don't have conclusive information what language or environment the web service is using, and am not interested in posting the name of the web service, distracting from my actual question.

Comment: A well designed service would return an exception if given not-well-formed XML, but there's no limit to   the bad behavior of a poorly designed service.

Comment: @kjhughes ok, that actually is a scenario I hadn't thought of. If I understand you correctly, if bad XML is sent to a web service, they could just sit on it and not respond. If they didn't respond at all, then all I would see on my end is a timeout error. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, but realize that *they could just sit on it* may very well be unintentional.  Note further that whether any program terminates, local or remote, cannot be determined a priori in the general case anyway.  See [**halting problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).